# custom user model name in django 1.5

Tags: django

In django administration site, i have a table name "auth" and rows "groups" and "user" (user and groupes model). I want to change the name "auth" and (groups and user).

Comment: do you speak about translation purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

The Django documentation talks about how to override the normal UserAdmin form

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    verbose_name = "whatever"
    verbose_name_plural = "whatevers"

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```